# Converting between WCHAR* to wstring without use of constructor

Tags: c++

I have a wchar array I need to write data into using a winapi function, and I want to get it in a `std::wstring`, I know `std::wstring t(wText);` works but I can't have it declared in an an if statement because it wouldn't exist outside that scope. Also I can't call the constructor in this fashion:

```
    WCHAR wText[256];

    std::wstring t = L"";
    if (somecondition)
    {
        t = t(wText); 
    }
```

What can I do? I want the `wstring` to be equal to  `""` when the condition is not met and when it is met I want to get a WCHAR array into it.

Comment: are you just looking for `t = std::wstring(wText);`?

Comment: Yep, thank you! Maybe want to post it as an answer?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can construct a temporary `std::wstring` object by calling the constructor in the expression like so:

```
t = std::wstring(wText);
```

Comment: huh.  Why not `std::wstring t; if (somecondition) t.assign(wText);`